# fb iframe application: 405 error

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-405

my application works fine without iframe, returns 405 error at facebook! why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `POST for Canvas` on the application settings, under the "advanced" tab.

Comment: Ideally, you should prepare for it. Check out FB's dev blog and the roadmap.

Comment: is this still possible? i don't see that setting in the application settings.

Comment: @split19 POST for canvas is now default for all apps. This referred to a temporary reversal available at the time.

Answer (score 16):

For reference I had this same 405 error. This was because my Facebook app was pointing to a .html file for testing.

I renamed to .aspx and my server stopped sending that error back to Facebook

Comment: Very good answer, to use an extension that's POSTable to by the web server.  I'm unable to configure my host's web server so this answer works best for me: to change the page extension over which I do have control. Thanks. My guess is that .PHP and other dynamic page extensions would work too.

Comment: if it still does not work for you, check the default file for aspx pages. in my case it was default.aspx, so simply renaming my index.html to index.aspx did not work. once I added index.aspx as a default, it started working.

Comment: This worked for me. Somewhat annoying that this is required though - not sure why Facebook won't accept an index file with a .html extension. Not all Facebook apps require complex server side code

Answer (score 0):

When using nginx server, this can be caused by pointing root of the web to .html file... Change it e.g to .php and it will work.

This is probabl because nginx does not allow POST method on static websites.